# Hardest tongue twister seen

Tags: pronunciation, speech, list-request

What is the hardest tongue twister you have ever seen? Humorous ones are also welcome.

Comment: I read that the "The sixth sick Sheik's sixth sheep is sick" holds the Guinness record as the world's hardest tongue twister but playing with a new [tongue twister game](http://www.pronouncepronounce.com/) I recently downloaded, I found this one the most difficult: *There are two minutes difference from four to two to two to two, from two to two to two,
too.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've always liked

> Peter Piper picked a peck of pickled peppers. How many pickled peppers did Peter Piper pick?

Comment: I'm kind of surprised this was the accepted answer.  I'm not surprised it is not the leading vote-getter.  It is one of the least difficult-to-say tongue twisters out there.  Actually, I'm not even sure I would call it a tongue twister at all (but for the fact that it is commonly accepted as such); to me it's just an example of alliteration.

Answer (score 20):

From the various tongue twister collections you can find ([English Tongue Twisters](http://www.uebersetzung.at/twister/en.htm), [alpha dictionary English Tongue-Twisters](http://www.alphadictionary.com/fun/tongue-twisters/english_tongue_twisters.html), [English club Tongue-Twisters](http://www.englishclub.com/pronunciation/tongue-twisters.htm), ...), one of the hardest is the classic:

> The sixth sick Sheik's sixth sheep is sick.

But that will obviously vary depending on your accent and region.
As illustrated by this [college exercise](http://international.ouc.bc.ca/pronunciation/#Layer6), it can be a way to improve some specific pronunciation.

Comment: You forgot [The socks of the Archduchess, are they dry or bone dry?](http://translate.google.com/#fr|en|Les%20chaussettes%20de%20l%27archi-duchesse%2C%20sont-elles%20s%C3%A8ches%20ou%20archi-s%C3%A8ches) :)

Comment: I can barely say the sick Shiek one, but have no trouble at all with Peter Piper.

Comment: Lordy. The only way I can say this one is with a two-second pause between words while I rearrange my tongue. Tongue-twister indeed.

Comment: Yep, "The sixth sick sheikh's sixth sheep's sick." with the apostrophized "sheep" is easily the toughest one I've come across.  The words just blur into one unless I purposely put a pause between each one.  :-)

Answer (score 9):

There is always the pheasant plucker, it is very difficult indeed in polite society :)

There is a song: http://www.users.globalnet.co.uk/~mentor01/song.htm

Comment: +1 for giving me a good laugh first thing in the morning :)

Comment: The first time I heard this was in my Drama class, as "I'm a mother pheasant plucker / I like to pluck mother pheasants / I'm the most pleasant mother pheasant plucker / who ever plucked a mother pheasant." We were challenged to recite it as quickly as possible. All others failed to much laughter and embarrassment, but I recited it perfectly on the first go, then punctuated the end with a great shout of "motherf—er!" Good times.

Answer (score 8):

> She sells sea-shells on the sea-shore.
>   The shells she sells are sea-shells
>   I'm sure.

This one is interesting as it refers to a real person with a fascinating life: [Mary Anning](http://www.associatedcontent.com/article/1453430/the_story_of_mary_anning_shell_seller.html), a self-taught fossilist.

Comment: Bonus points for interesting side-note.

Answer (score 7):

One of the simplest is repeating "Toy Boat" aloud as fast as possible.

Comment: Similarly, "red leather, yellow leather".

Comment: Which is similar to red lorry, yellow lorry.

Comment: @Sky - this is my favorite so I added it as an answer

Answer (score 6):

The incredibly short

> Irish wristwatch

has always been difficult for me.

Comment: Not heard of this before. Totally stumpping!

Comment: +1 - Automatically turn into Sean Connery when saying this one.

Answer (score 4):

I always liked:

> The Leith police dismisseth us.

(Leith is an area of Edinburgh, pronounced to rhyme with 'teeth'.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if this falls under tongue-twister, but I've always loved it.

> Betty Botter bought some butter,
> But, she said, The butter's bitter;
> If I put it in my batter
> It will make my batter bitter.
> But, a bit of better butter
> Will make my batter better.
>
> So, she bought a bit of butter
> Better than her bitter butter,
> And she put it in her batter
> And the batter was not bitter.
> So, 'twas better Betty Botter
> Bought a bit of better butter.

Answer (score 4):

Lorry is a British English word for a large truck and allows us to use "red lorry, yellow lorry" which is about as hard as it gets.

Comment: Nice. This one is so hard, most people trip the second time they say it.

Answer (score 3):

While not the most difficult, one of my favorites is "Rubber baby buggy bumpers."

Comment: I appreciate the fact that you acknowledge it's not that difficult.  I agree with you that it's cute and fun. :)

Answer (score 3):

Almost anything from Dr Seuss, especially his

> bed spreaders spread spreads on beds and bread spreaders spread butter on breads

and:

> tweetle beetle paddle puddle battle

and from Fox in Socks, anything to do with

> chicks and clocks, bricks and blocks.

Not terribly tough but lots of fun.

And this one from a ladybird phonics book:

> Thin chips, thick chips,
>   lick-your-lips chips.

Comment: What do you know about Tweetle Beetles?  (Anything from *Fox in Socks*).

Answer (score 3):

This is one that is hard to say quick:

> **Red Robin, the red river rat, ran right round the the rabbit's rickety rocking chair, and rubbed his rosy, rusty, red rump on the rumpled red rug.**

Answer (score 2):

> Unique New York

Is a favorite of mine.

Answer (score 1):

I've always liked this (juvenile) one, from the Steve Martin film "The Jerk":

> I slit the sheet;
>   The sheet I slit.
>   Upon the slitted sheet I sit.

Answer (score 1):

Contiguous mnemonic anomalies. We had to be able to say this 10 times rapidly to graduate from my GIS class.

Comment: What is a GIS class?

Comment: @martha - Geographic Information Systems. And we didn't really, we just joked that we had to...

Answer (score 1):

A cycle rally is different from lorry rally.

Answer (score 1):

One of my personal favorites:

> Fuzzy Wuzzy was a bear.  Fuzzy Wuzzy had no hair.  Fuzzy Wuzzy wasn't fuzzy, was he?

Answer (score 0):

One of my favorites: "blue-black bug's blood."

Answer (score 0):

More of a 'bum-twister' really, and definitely beneath me, but I always liked

[**What about a water bottle, Wibble?**](http://board.jokeroo.com/funny-jokes/768-water-bottle.html)

Answer (score 0):

I always like the old Wood Chuck. I am surprised that nobody said anything about it yet.

> How much wood would a woodchuck chuck
>   If a woodchuck could chuck wood?
>   He would chuck, he would, as much as he could,
>   And chuck as much as a woodchuck would
>   If a woodchuck could chuck wood.